# Redirección en laravel a otra ruta manteniendo parámetro

Tags: php, laravel, rutas, redirección

estoy intentado hacer una redireción con Laravel a una ruta con un id que varia, y quería saber como poder recoger el id ya existente en la URL

Esta es la ruta

```
 Route::get('/home/{id?}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('auth');
```

y quisiera hacer una redirección a otra ruta manteniendo el id que ya viene de la ruta home

```
Route::get('/events/{id?}', 'EventsController@get')->middleware('auth')->name('events.get');
```

Intenté hacer esto y funciona pero quisiera recoger el id de la url

```
 return redirect()
            ->route('events.get')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné haciendo lo siguiente:

```
        // Recoger URL actual antes de redireccionar
        $url =$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        //recoger la ultima parte de la URL (que es la id)
        $result = preg_match('(([^/]*)/*$)', $url, $m) ? $m[1] : f(function() use ($url) {throw new e("pattern on '$url'");});

        return redirect()->route('eventos.get', ['id' => $result])   

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes añadir la función `to` y añadir un array con el elemento que esperas

```
$id = $request->input('id');
return redirect()->to(route('events.get', ['id' => $id]));
```